# How to get privacy photos from facebook for friends+ permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get from facebook photos that have friends (+) permissions.

i run this query on the graph api

Select object_id from privacy where object_id in (list of objects ids that represent the photos I want to filter) where value != custom

But its give me also objects that have just friends permissions (so the friends of the tagged users of the object can not see the object)

What to do?